# Slick Slider css has `\9` in margin rule

Tags: css

[It was](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/commit/abf7eeb48d045f9abc053144e5b934679beb325a#diff-12c48723bb8ab1439a9502269845e4aa):

```
margin-top: -10px;
```

and now is:

```
margin-top: -10px\9; /*lte IE 8*/
```

Is this a typo or is there a reason for it?

Comment: This is a "CSS Hack" for IE like explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: and here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13571909/1606432

Comment: This is why commits have messages. The commit message gives precisely the explanation you're looking for. Even the comment in the line of code you copied contains an abridged version of the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "CSS Hack" for IE, to make it render properly.

Comment: You could add some references for brevity. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks, yes this example would help him understand well.